# error when trying to remount / readonly

Tags: debian, mount

On my Debian wheezy system I'm trying to remount / readonly.
I switch to runlevel 1 and then issue

```
mount / -o ro, remount
```

which always errors out with "`column: invalid argument`"

#### Additional findings

There's no difference if I leave out the space after the comma and this only happens with `bash`, it properly works when using `dash`.

Comment: You've got a space inbetween the comma and ```remount```, that appears to be a syntax error, can you try without the space?

Answer (score 2):

You have a space between "ro," and "remount". Try without this space.